# code twig in javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony

In my template Twig i hope to use a loop for into javascript,so i tried this but it doesn't work :

```
series: [{
  name: 'Population',
  data: [{% for SoResult in SoResults %} SoResult.pollanswerPoints {% endfor %}],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
```

and i have this error:

```
missing ) after argument list
[Stopper sur une erreur]    
SoResult.pollanswerPoints
```

And i would like to have something like that :

```
data : [44,58,69]
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
series: [{
    name: 'Population',
    data: [
        {% for SoResult in SoResults %}
            {# write a comma to separate elements unless it is first one... #}
            {% if loop.index0 != 0 %},{% endif %}
            {# it's important to write quotes if elements are string in Javascript #}
            "{{SoResult.pollanswerPoints}}"
        {% endfor %}
    ],
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,  ...
```